# How to send the whole state json data from server to react client using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

Basically, this snippet below is what I have on my client side to set my state only for the timestamp, but I want to set all of my json data here.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  subscribeToTimer((err, timestamp) => this.setState({ 
    timestamp
  })); 
}
```

that is what I have inside api component, note that I want to place the json data from the server initially here.

```
   import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';

   const  socket = openSocket('http://localhost:8000');

   function subscribeToTimer(cb) {
     socket.on('timer', timestamp => cb(null, timestamp));
     //socket.on(wooOrderId = > )
     socket.emit('subscribeToTimer', 1000);
   }
   export { subscribeToTimer };
```

And below is my server code for the timestamp, I want to set all of my json data over here in order to transfer it to my client, correct me if I am wrong somewhere, much appreciate you, thx.

```
  const io = require('socket.io')();

  io.on('connection', (client) => {
    client.on('subscribeToTimer', (interval) => {
      console.log('client is subscribing to timer with interval ', interval);
      setInterval(() => {
        client.emit('timer', new Date());
      }, interval);
    });
  });

  const port = 8000;
  io.listen(port);
  console.log('listening on port ', port);
```

The basic scheme was done according to the [tutorial](https://medium.com/dailyjs/combining-react-with-socket-io-for-real-time-goodness-d26168429a34)

Comment: Where' s the problem ? Replace `timestamp` with the `newState` you want. And change state using `this.setState(newState)`

Comment: I have it replaced accordingly, now it works, also is there a vast difference when I pass an array of objects and just objects

Comment: It has to be an object, since react state has to be an object. Wrap the array in an object if you want.

Comment: I have the same question. There isn't a answer. I can send the Date but not any other sort of Object